# React jest snapshot pass test every time

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am using create-react-app 16.2 with Jest 22. I start the test with 
`yarn test`.
Snapshot test at the first run creates snapshot file but the snapshot does not cover entire component, only `<Accordion>` component which is the first `<div>` in the output. After `<Accordion>` comes `<Modal>` section but it is not rendered into snap file.
What am I doing wrong ?

Summary.test.js:

```
    /**
 * @jest-environment node
 */

import React from 'react'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import Summary from './Summary';

it('should match its snapshot without content', () => {
  const tree = renderer
    .create(<Summary />)
    .toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
})
```

Summary.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Segment, Icon, Header, Accordion, Modal, Image, Button, List } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export default class ItemGroup extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            open: false,
        };
    }

    show = dimmer => () => this.setState({ dimmer, open: true })
    close = () => this.setState({ open: false })
    openMail = () => {
        let message = ``
        const { content } = this.props;
        let selectedItems = `Dear Sirs,%0A%0A
        I am interested in following configuration: %0A`
        for(let item in content) {
            selectedItems+=`-> ${content[item].text}%0A`
        }
        window.location.href = `mailto:user@example.com?subject=Request%20for%20offer&body=${selectedItems}%0A%0A`;
    }
  render() {
        const { content } = this.props;
        const { open, dimmer } = this.state;
        let selectedItems = '0 items selected';

        if(content) {
            selectedItems =  Object.keys(content).map( item => 
            <List.Item key={content[item].text}> {content[item].text} </List.Item>
            )
        }

    return (
            <div style={{marginBottom:'-10px'}}>
                <Accordion.Title index={this.props.index} onClick={this.show('blurring')}>
                    <Segment style={{ padding:'0px', display:'flex', backgroundColor:'rgba(217, 103, 103, 0.867)', color:'black' }}>
                        <Header as='h1'size='huge'>
                            <Icon name='ordered list' style={{ fontSize: '2em', padding: '0em 1.3em' }} />
                            <Header.Content> Summary </Header.Content>
                        </Header>
                    </Segment>
                </Accordion.Title>
                <Modal dimmer={dimmer} open={open} onClose={this.close}>
          <Modal.Header>Configuration summary</Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Content image>
            <Image wrapped size='medium' src='/asset/molly.png' />
            <Modal.Description>
              <Header>You have selected following items:</Header>
                            <List celled ordered>
                                {selectedItems} 
                        </List>
            </Modal.Description>
          </Modal.Content>
          <Modal.Actions>
            <Button color='black' onClick={this.close}>
              TEREFERE
            </Button>
            <Button positive icon='mail outline' labelPosition='right' content="Send E-mail" onClick={this.openMail} />
          </Modal.Actions>
        </Modal>
            </div>
        );
  }
}

ItemGroup.propTypes  = {
    index: PropTypes.number,
    content: PropTypes.object,
}
```

Summary.test.js.snap:

```
// Jest Snapshot v1, 

exports[`should match its snapshot without content 1`] = `
<div
  style={
    Object {
      "marginBottom": "-10px",
    }
  }
>
  <div
    className="title"
    onClick={[Function]}
  >
    <div
      className="ui segment"
      style={
        Object {
          "backgroundColor": "rgba(217, 103, 103, 0.867)",
          "color": "black",
          "display": "flex",
          "padding": "0px",
        }
      }
    >
      <h1
        className="ui huge header"
      >
        <i
          aria-hidden="true"
          className="ordered list icon"
          style={
            Object {
              "fontSize": "2em",
              "padding": "0em 1.3em",
            }
          }
        />
        <div
          className="content"
        >
           Summary 
        </div>
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
`;
```

Comment: And does `Modal` render anything when it has `open` prop equal `false`?

Comment: Good point :) anyhow I have changed to  open: true,  so the window should open immediately, but it is still not rendered in the snapshot file. Probably I will need to separate `<Accordion>` and `<Modal>` into 2 components tested separately.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you have not passed `trigger` prop into your `Modal` component.

Look at the source of the component in the library you're using ([semantic-ui-react](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React)):

[Modal](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/master/src/modules/Modal/Modal.js#L354) component uses [Portal](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/master/src/addons/Portal/Portal.js#L430) component which has this code:

```
if (!trigger) return null
```

I guess this is the source of your problem :)